# Is image of the cup-product actually a homomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Given a simplicial complex $K$, its simplicial cochain complex $C^\bullet(K) = C_\bullet(K)^\vee = Hom(C_\bullet(K), \mathbb{Z})$, as well as $p,q \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $\sigma := \{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_{p+q} \} \in K_{p+q}$, the *Cup product* is commonly defined as follows:

$$
\cup : C^p(K) \times C^q(K) \to C^{p+q}(K) \\
(\phi, \psi)(\sigma) \mapsto (\phi \cup \psi)(\sigma) :=  \phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p \}) \cdot \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_q \})
$$

Now, why is the resulting map $(\phi \cup \psi) : C_{p+q}(K) \to \mathbb{Z}$ actually linear, i. e. a group homomorphism $C^{p+q}(K) = Hom(C_{p+q}, \mathbb{Z})$? After all, it seems we have:

\begin{align*}
(\phi \cup \psi)(\sigma + \sigma) & = (\phi \cup \psi)(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\} + \{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) \\
& = \phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\} + \{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\}) \cdot \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\} + \{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) \\
& =(\phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\}) + \phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\})) \cdot (\psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) + \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\})) \\
& =\phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\}) \cdot \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) + \phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\}) \cdot \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) \\
& \qquad + \phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\}) \cdot \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) + \phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\}) \cdot \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) \\
& =(\phi \cup \psi)(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_{q + p}\}) + (\phi \cup \psi)(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_{q + p}\}) \\
& \qquad + \phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\}) \cdot \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) + \phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\}) \cdot \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) \\
& \stackrel{(*)}{\neq} (\phi \cup \psi)(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_{q + p}\}) + (\phi \cup \psi)(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_{q + p}\}) \\
& = (\phi \cup \psi)(\sigma) + (\phi \cup \psi)(\sigma)
\end{align*}

$(*)$: provided that $\phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\}) \cdot \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) + \phi(\{ \sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_p\}) \cdot \psi(\{ \sigma_p, \dots, \sigma_{p+q}\}) \neq 0$ which can easily granted for a proper choice of $\phi$, $\psi$ and $\sigma$.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You define the value of the cup product $\phi \smile \psi$ on individual simplices.  Then, there exists a unique linear extension to the free abelian group generated by such.